# Count number of true variables in a boolean expression

Tags: math, boolean, predicate, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

How do I write a boolean expression that is able to verify the amount of variables that are set to true? I will provide a simplified example of the problem I am trying to solve. Please read the whole question before answering because the actual question is at the very end.

**Declarations:**

> 3 boolean variables: **a b c**
>
> int **expected** = 2

How do I write a boolean expression that is able to verify that out of the 3 boolean variables there are exactly 2 set to true. Something along the lines of `problem = (a + b + c) == 2` where `problem` would be true if **exactly** 2 of the boolean variables are set to true.

That is the simplified version of the problem, with exactly 3 boolean variables and expected = 2 we can solve the problem with `problem = (a & b) | (b & c) | (c & a)`

My question however is, how do we solve this using **n** number of boolean variables, and a varying amount for the **expected** variable using **first order logic** including logical connectives, predicates, and quantifiers.

I want to stress that I am not looking for actual code from any specific language but just a proposition/predicate expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that `false` resolves to 0 and `true` to 1, then you could do:

`ans = ((a + b + c + ... + z) == expected)`

Where `a..z` are boolean variables (possibly results from other expressions' evaluations) and `expected` is the number of true conditions that you want.

Comment: The question I have however is how do I write `ans = ((a + b + c + ... + z) == expected)` using only first order logic, that is where I am stuck.